# Syntax error while importing the module on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, syntax-error, binance

After a first phase of testing among different Binance API alternative implementations i decided to try the most diffused one: python-binance.

I'm using Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I installed the module with the following command

```
pip3 install python-binance
```

Everything was fine so i decided to run my first test script:

```
import time
import os
from binance.client import Client

api_key = 'my_binance_api'
api_secret = 'my_binance_secret'

client = Client(my_api_key, my_binance_secret )
```

Unfortunatly i got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prova.py", line 1, in <module>
    from binance.client import Client
  File "/myhome/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/binance/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from binance.client import Client, AsyncClient  # noqa
  File "/myhome/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 41
    REQUEST_TIMEOUT: float = 10
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Thx

Comment: Is there any way you can upgrade your python version?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Is it mandatory for binance-api or just a suggestion?

Comment: @technoleap84 Mandatory. Binance seems to require a newer Python version than yours.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks. I've had a really bad experience with broken pip3 in the past so i decided to keep the version at 3.5.  The fastest way to upgrade without headaches linked with pip3?

Comment: You could use Docker if you really want a quick way to test if a new version would work. Otherwise, `apt install python3-pip` should not break anything, but you need a new PPA to get a newer python, I think

Comment: Regardless, `typing` module was introduced in Python 3.5, so, I'm not sure why this isnt working

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @OneCricketeer above, i installed a new version of python (3.8) and then, after forcing the reinstall of python-binance via a new version of PIP (unfortunalty mine gets broken) Binance package start working.

I'm gonna list the procedure (including PIP tweaks) just in case someone else out there wanted to avoid useless and unhealty headaches:

```
pip install python3.x
    
    pip sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 1 #update the manager
    
    sudo update-alternatives --config python (chose the latest version)
    
    curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

    sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils

    python get-pip.py
```

Use always

```
python -m pip
```

to manage the modules

Thanks